# Python: sqlite no matching distribution found for sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pip

I tried to install that library by pip in console. I'm using win7 and python v. 2.7.10. But failed to achive. Acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976019/how-to-get-table-name-of-the-executed-query-python-sqlite) - It can be used for my version of python too.

I tried to install by several ways:

> pip install sqlite
>
> pip install sqlite3
>
> pip install sqlite-devel

What is wrong here?

```
    Full error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement(). 
No matching distribution found for ...
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What makes you think you need to install this? sqlite is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), and does not need installing.

Comment: Because I dont have such lib installed. `import sqlite` - doesn't work

Comment: The stdlib module is called sqlite3. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Because the package `sqlite3` (in the standard library) has problems. Try compiling a sqlite3 python program with cx_Freeze, and you'll get a DLL not found error.

Comment: Old one but gold one :), I was astonished why it is working if it is not installed

Comment: after stubbornly trying to download SQLITE3 from pip for several minutes, i remembered that python is batteries included.

Comment: What's the solution for this? On Windows I see the folder for the sqlite in the python install directory and I updated the path environment variable to include this path, but in VS code, it's still complaining that the command is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in RHEL7.4 
it worked with below solution

If you compiled and installed Python 3 yourself, install the dependencies (**libsqlite3-dev** or **sqlite-devel** or similar, depending on your Linux distribution, for example), then re-compile and re-install Python 3.

after installing the **sqlite-devel** I have reinstall Python3.6 on my machine using below steps

1. download wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tar.xz
2. tar xvf Python-3.6.3.tar.xz
3. cd Python-3.6.3 and then run ./configure
4. make
5. make install

after doing this when I launch ***jupyter notebook*** it got launch

Credit goes for this answer to Martijn Link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440858/5863866

Comment: I'm new to python, django..I'm working on Python-Django project, I have been facing the same error even after installing sqlite-devel I'm getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' "

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution would be

`pip install pysqlite`

Comment: This was merged into Python code in 2006. https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite?tab=readme-ov-file#pysqlite

Answer (score -1):

I tried to install that library by pip in console. I'm using windows12 and python version. 3.10.11. But it failed to achive. Acording to this - It can be used for my version of python too.

I tried to install by several ways:

pip install sqlite

pip install sqlite3

pip install sqlite-devel

What is wrong here?

```
Full error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement().
```

No matching distribution found for ...

I used "pip install pysqlite"** and it worked(it works succesfully❤️

Comment: This was merged into Python code in 2006. https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite?tab=readme-ov-file#pysqlite

Answer (score -2):

I used "pip install pysqlite" and it worked

Comment: What is the difference with Harshit Garg's answer which was posted 4 years ago?

Comment: This was merged into Python code in 2006. https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite?tab=readme-ov-file#pysqlite