# sqlite3 is not be able to import in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

sqlite is working fine with python 2.7 but when I am trying to import this in python 3 it gives error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dbConnection.py", line 1,
> in <module>
>     import sqlite3   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
>     from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

to remove this error I am trying to reinstall sqlite3 by

```
 sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

but it says that package is already exists. After that I am trying to install it by

```
pip3 install sqlite3
```

but again while installing it gives error

```
Collecting sqlite3
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/sqlite3/
 Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/sqlite3/
 Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after  connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb5ff3bc550>, 'Connection to 196.1.114.80 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/sqlite3/
 Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/sqlite3/
 Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/sqlite3/
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

but my connection is working fine ...
Now what should I do so that I am able to import sqlite3 in python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sqlite3` is an *optional* part of the standard library. It is compiled when you compile and install Python 3, but only if the right `sqlite3` include files (development headers) are available.

If you compiled and installed Python 3 yourself, install the dependencies (`libsqlite3-dev` or `sqlite-devel` or similar, depending on your Linux distribution, for example), then re-compile and re-install Python 3.

Externally, the library is maintained as [`pysqlite`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite); but [that release doesn't support Python 3](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/72). Even then, to install it you'll still need those `sqlite` development files, and you'd need to port it to Python 3. You may as well just re-compile Python 3.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I already installed libsqlite3-dev as suggested by some site but nothing work... :(

Comment: Get an error while compiling:

    *** WARNING: renaming "_sqlite3" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_stmt_readonly

From https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/85, it might be caused by the older sqlite version.