# sqlite ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 Google App Engine

Tags: python, sqlite, google-app-engine, flask

I am attempting to deploy a Python Flask, HTML, JavaScript web application through Google App Engine.

I'm using sqlite3 for my database

```
 >>> python
 >>> import sqlite3
```

This works just fine. Deploying my web app with

```
$ gcloud app deploy
```

Works just fine.

However when I visit the page, I receive this message

*Error: Server Error*

*The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.*

And when I check the Error Reporting at https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/941d77da994078b1/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/941d77da994078b1/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/941d77da994078b1/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~live-business-solutions/20191010t190446.421644656225294026/webapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from databasefunctions import *
  File "/base/data/home/apps/p~live-business-solutions/20191010t190446.421644656225294026/databasefunctions.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/941d77da994078b1/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/941d77da994078b1/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

It is from the line

`import sqlite3`

of my databasefunctions.py file. I'm not sure why this is, could anyone please help?

I was wondering if I am supposed to somehow include sqlite3 in requirements.txt? and if so how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440858/7757976):

> The `sqlite3` is an optional part of the standard library.

So it is not installed via `pip` and thus using the `requirements.txt` file. But it needs some package level dependencies `libsqlite3-dev` or `sqlite-devel` that don't come in the Google App Engine Python3 runtime. So it is not possible to use `sqlite3` on Google App Engine Standard.

The solution is to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/), which will allow you to run your application in a Docker container and you will be able to customize your runtime. You can start with this [Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869385/can-not-make-tesseract-work-in-google-app-engine-with-python3/58302467#58302467) that I provide about the same issue with other library.

Comment: Would it be bad to use a simple JSON file as a database? I don't care about security for this web app. However I noticed that you have to rewrite the whole file every change, would this be slow? There would only be 14 elements of said JSON, so would a 275 bytes file being read and rewritten be a big deal?

Comment: If I do go the route of using Cloud Run and running in a Docker container what should my Dockerfile look like? I notice that you added `#Install tesseract
RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy \
        tesseract-ocr \
        libtesseract-dev` to the Dockerfile of the answer you mentioned, I would replace this with some way of installing sqlite3?

Comment: such as `RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy \
        sqlite3 \
        libsqlite3-dev` and good to go?

Comment: Just install the packages `libsqlite3-dev` and `sqlite-devel`.  `RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy libsqlite3-dev \ sqlite-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands in centos for get ride of GCP slite3 import error during docker commands execution:

yum install -y gcc make sqlite-devel zlib-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel

**Need reconfigure python 3+version**

cd python3.9.6
./configure
make clean
make && make altinstall
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3

while checking /bin/python3 it has to return the 3.9.6 , if you are going to use 3.6 then that has to be reconfigured and symlink has to be created.

sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python  (Must to run otherwise YUM commands are not running)

/bin/python3 --version