Trouble with Importing sqlite Module in Python
I'm facing a problem with Python regarding the sqlite module. I have several versions of Python installed on my system:
mat@pc:~$ find /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10-config
/usr/bin/python3.11
/usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python3-futurize
/usr/bin/python3-pasteurize

When I try to import sqlite in Python 3.11, I get this error:
mat@pc:~$ python3.11
Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb 25 2024, 16:39:33) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite'

But when I use Python 3.10, the import works fine.
Also, when I check the Python version using python3 --version, I see Python 3.12.1. I'm wondering why there's this difference.
Could someone help me understand why I'm having these issues and how to solve them? Thank you for your help.

Are you trying to import sqlite3 from the standard library or a third-party module? If you're trying to import the standard library module, note that difference in the name. If you're trying to import a third-party module, make you that you installed it for the interpreter you're trying to import it with. For example, run python3.11 -m pip install <dist name> where <dist name> is the name of the distribution package that provides that sqlite module you want to use.

@Brian61354270 I'm trying to import the sqlite3 module from the standard library, not a third-party module.
Furthermore, when I installed Django, I encountered difficulties running the server due to an issue with sqlite. This led me to suspect that sqlite might not actually be part of the standard library, despite my initial assumption. However, I'm puzzled as to why everything is functioning correctly in Python 3.10.

In that case it's spelled sqlite3, not sqlite (note the 3). It is part of the standard library, and will exist unless there's something unusual about your Python installation (e.g. you tried compiling CPython from source with missing dependencies)

You are absolutely correct. However,  when I use import sqlite3 I got the following error: from _sqlite3 import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Did you compile CPython yourself? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41440749/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210664/

@Brian61354270 TY <3 Problem is solved.
