# No matching distribution found for sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pip

Guys every time I try to install sqlite3 with pip I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions:none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

My python version: **3.10.0**

My pip version: **21.3**

How can I solve this?  I believe it's regarding my version of python so how can i update the pip to fix this?  I've already tried this pip --upgrade pip

**Edited:**

Guys I installed python 3.7.0 and it's still the same thing.

Comment: Many libraries have not caught up to 3.10 yet. I recommend holding off for a bit longer. I ran into this attempting to use install torch. myself.

Comment: sqlite comes by default in python, there is no need to install it.

Comment: Can you clarify why you through you needed to install it? Are you following some guide?

Comment: Also, for future reference, if you're not having a version specific issue for Python (majority of issues are not), then only use `python` tag

Comment: @Eyllanesc I want to install other modules too

Comment: @Dkns 1. You do not have to install sqlite3 as it comes by default so you get the error. 2. what other modules do you want to install?

Comment: @Dkns The same, the `re` module also comes by default. I have a question: where did you get that you have to install sqlite3 and re?

Comment: StackOverflow is english only, please. As explained, Python (all versions) comes with these. Why are you trying to install them?

Comment: Do a page search on this for `sqlite` and `re` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html Nothing on this page needs to be installed

Comment: @OneCricketeer But why can't I install any packages?

Comment: You should be able to "install any package"... For example, `pip install requests` - works fine, right? Because [that actually **exists** in pypi](https://pypi.org/)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah you're right, but why when I try `pip install sys` I get this error?  or other modules I mentioned?  Sorry if the question is silly, I'm a Linux user, and windows has been a mystery to me

Comment: **Again** `sys` is built-in. Give a better example. This has nothing to do with your OS. Python is considered "batteries included". If it doesn't exist when you type in the PyPi search box, then pip doesn't know about it. What you're asking is like trying to install `string` or `int` in order to use it as a datatype

Comment: It's just that this error I mentioned in the question doesn't show up on Linux when I try to install the same things, I don't understand what this error means.

Comment: Just tried it on Linux, and I definitely get the same error

Comment: @Apostolos It's down voted because there is no explanation why this package is trying to be installed. If there was code that tried to use the package instead, then it should just work. Pip just isn't needed here

Comment: @OneCricketeer, no package is **"trying to be installed"**. Read the question again. **It is the user who tries to install it** and it can't be installed. And there is an explanation for that. It is given below. So there **is** an answer to this question. Which means that the question is good. In fact, it has more upvotes than the downvotes given to the question. And, wait a minute, as I see, this answer is from you!   Don't you think that something is wrong here?

Comment: @Apostolos Yes. `pip install sqlite3` was ran. Therefore, it was tried to be installed. That's just not necessary, and no official Python documentation says that command is necessary. Therefore, _question does not show research effort_ (which is shown on hover text of the down arrow)

Comment: OK @OneCricketeer, from that aspect you are right. But this is besides my main point, anyway. I can't talk about it anymore. I did that enough.

Answer (score 4):

See [Python: sqlite no matching distribution found for sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605677/python-sqlite-no-matching-distribution-found-for-sqlite)

[`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is part of [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html), meaning it is *already installed* with Python.

You can write a script following the documentation, and notice it says nothing about installation procedures.

The error is self-explanatory. For anything that **can** be installed with `pip`, you should refer to the source - [PyPi](https://pypi.org/). Search for `sqlite3` and notice that you get no *exact match*

---

Many languages have built-in modules, for example, you seem to have maybe some NodeJS experience, so you can import things like `os`, `readline`, `net`, `http` modules **without** needing to `npm install`. You simply `require` them.

Python/Pip is no different with a simple `import`.

> this error I mentioned in the question doesn't show up on Linux when I try to install the same things

Is that so? Seems to work for me (Using Docker because I'm on a Mac)

```
$ docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint=ash python:3.10-alpine
Unable to find image 'python:3.10-alpine' locally
3.10-alpine: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:78604a29496b7a1bd5ea5c985d69a0928db7ea32fcfbf71bbde3e317fdd9ac5e
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.10-alpine
/ # pip install sqlite3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```