# Extracting the table from the query

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT a.name, a.state_desc, b.start_date, b.modify_date, b.percentage_complete  
FROM sys.databases AS a  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_database_copies AS b ON a.database_id = b.database_id  
WHERE a.state = 7;
```

I want to extract the table name from the query which in this case is the `databases`

How can I do it? I am mostly concerned with fetching the database table name immediately after the `From` clause, any guidance how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract table names and column names from sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624662/how-to-extract-table-names-and-column-names-from-sql-query)

Comment: In general you could just chuck the SQL in a throw away proc and then look at `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` - but annoyingly this doesn't work for `sys.databases` - maybe it doesn't record dependencies on system objects